# Customize the mock data defined against the types in graphql-tools

Tags: graphql-js, graphql-tools

I am using graphql-tools to mock for my UI (create-react-app) functional tests. I have a question around the MockList

Currently, I am mocking by type and one of the properties is an array but I still need to be able to customise the elements in the list

e.g. I have a `LineItem` type which has a mock defined as

```
const LineItem = () =>
  ({
    name: 'Item name'
  } as LineItemType)
```

and the cart type has a list of `LineItem`

```
const Cart = () =>
  ({
    id: 'cart-id',
    lineItems: [...new Array(2)],
  } as ActiveCartType)
```

Is there a way for the item name to be different for the 2 items in the cart?

I tried to map over the Array like so

```
const Cart = () =>
  ({
    id: 'cart-id',
    lineItems: [...new Array(2)].map(i => ({...i, id: '123', name: 'new item name'})),
  } as ActiveCartType)
```

But the `name` doesn't change in the mock result. It is still set to `Item name`. Only `id` changes to `123`.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`graphql-tools/mocking`](https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/blob/a1baf773a5ce92da722372326be1259c6ef24c66/website/docs/mocking.md#customizing-mocks)

> we are using casual, a fake data generator for JavaScript, so that we can get a different result every time the field is called. You might want to use a collection of fake objects, or a generator that always uses a consistent seed, if you are planning to use the data for testing.

From your code, you could assign `name` to a generator function that adds unique names to that field.

```
  const LineItem = () =>
  ({
    name: functionGoesHere()
  } as LineItemType)
```

Two libraries that produce generated data for mocking are,

- [Casual library](https://github.com/boo1ean/casual)
- [Faker.js Library](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/)